# RESOLVED (arithmetic series) I dont get how this works logically

Tags: sequences-and-series

[click to see the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHnnQ.png)

so for the last part, using the formula for the sum of the arithmetic sequence, the answer is 37 weeks to get 350 bucks. my question is howw??? because the difference between each term is 25 cents, so to get 345 more dollars you would need 1380 weeks after the first one to get the total. 37 just seems absolutely absurd to me. someone please, I beg you to explain this to me in a non formula based way.
I apologize in advance if this was a really stupid question.

Comment: You are misreading the question. The second week you save an additional $5.25,$ not an additional $0.25.$ It’s true that the question could be clearer. After $2$ weeks, she has saved $10.25.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my bad, i do this a lot

Comment: It is awkwardly phrased, no reason to apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you misunderstood the question.

It's not saying that after 2 weeks she saved £5.25. Rather it says that on the 2nd week she saved £5.25.

So simply you can say that the money required is:$$\text{5*number of weeks + 0.25*(number of weeks -1)}$$

Now for clarification,

$\text{5*number of weeks}$ means she saved £5 every month for sure.

And, $\text{0.25*(number of weeks-1)}$ is just the arithmetic sequence formula of the series $\text{0,0.25,0.50,0.75,...}$

Comment: What you did was just $\frac{34500}{25}$ but that's the mistake....

Comment: thank you! i would upvote it but my account it not old enough. But I very much appreciate both Thomas and Your answers!